# HandlebarsJS: display sum of number of objects in a JSON Array?

Tags: html, json, templates, handlebars.js

I have the following simple `handlebarsjs` email HTML template:

```
<script id="emailTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div>
       Hi {{name }} , you have submitted {{ SUM_OF_ARRAY_OBJECTS}} cars. Thanks.
    </div>
</script>
```

With the `json` content:

```
{
  "name": "john",
  "cars": [
    {
      "registration": "stubReg1",
      "year": "1995"
    },
    {
      "registration": "stubReg2",
      "year": "2000"
    },
    {
      "registration": "stubReg3",
      "year": "2010"
    },
    {
      "registration": "stubReg4",
      "year": "2016"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I display the total number of array objects in the `SUM_OF_ARRAY_OBJECTS` placeholder using handlebars? i.e. 4 in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an answer to this which was more simple than I thought:

`{{cars.length}}` will show the sum of the number of objects in the array.